# Tensorflow and PyCharm autocomplete problem

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a problem with autocomplete in PyCharm and tensor flow, I have a sample code which runs perfectly, but the problem in my IDE which can't show autocomplete code option.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

Mnist_dataSet, Mnist_Info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
Mnist_Train, Mnist_Test = Mnist_dataSet['train'], Mnist_dataSet['test']

num_validation_sample = 0.1 * Mnist_Info.splits['train'].num_examples #No code complete option
num_validation_sample = tf.cast(num_validation_sample, tf.int64)

num_Test_sample =0.1*Mnist_Info.splits['test'].num_examples  #No code complete option
num_Test_sample = tf.cast(num_Test_sample, tf.int64)
.....
......
```

I know python is dynamically programming language and at declaring variable it declares like this

```
Mnist_dataSet: Any = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

I try to declare variables like this and it works

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

Mnist_Info: tfds.core.DatasetInfo
Mnist_dataSet, Mnist_Info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
Mnist_Train, Mnist_Test = Mnist_dataSet['train'], Mnist_dataSet['test']

num_validation_sample = 0.1 * Mnist_Info.splits['train'].num_examples
num_validation_sample = tf.cast(num_validation_sample, tf.int64)

num_Test_sample =0.1*Mnist_Info.splits['test'].num_examples
num_Test_sample = tf.cast(num_Test_sample, tf.int64)
```

Is there any option to make python declare variables according to the main class automatically?

Comment: any help or suggest?